# Fix angular checkBox

Tags: html, css, angular, checkbox, layout

[image]

This **UI** is produced by following code ....means **checkboxes** are not aligned properly . They are being displayed on extreme left and extreme right .

```
<div class="sample">
        <div align="left" class="user-modified-rule">
            <mat-checkbox (change)="changeSelectionTo()" [(ngModel)]="isChangeRule"></mat-checkbox>
            <rule> </rule>
       </div>
        <div class="ruleSpearator"> OR</div>
        <div align="right" class="production-stage-rule">
            <mat-checkbox (change)="changeSelectionTo()" [(ngModel)]="isOriginalRule"></mat-checkbox>
            <rule> </rule>

        </div>
</div>
```

**and i want the **UI** as shows in images below**
I need to align the checkbox along with `<rule>` as in code
[image]

if i change code

```
<mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
<rule></rule>
```

to

````
<mat-checkbox>
   <rule></rule>
</mat-checkbox>```

then entire rule becomes clickable..means any where click on rule , does the checkbox check and uncheck , which i do not want to
````

Comment: Use Css Flexbox

Comment: can u provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular flex layout

import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <div fxFlex="50px">    
        <mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex>
        <rule></rule>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this...but adding of new module is not allowed...i have to manipulate CSS only